# Linux bash script： Move sourcefiles to backup folder every night

Tags: bash

We have a `cron` job to process or handle many input source files in one directory. After processing, input source files are backed up. We want to write a script to move input soource files to a targeted backup folder.

Surpose input source files are `/source/input/`, backup folder are `/target/backup/`.

Comment: I have my own answer. It is self answered question. It is here for my own knowledge. And share with someone who might have same interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bash scripts are listed as follows, NOTE: Since the script is put into a cron job, so

1) directory or file path shall be better as absolute path in order avoid unfound error.

2) target directory is not cross over with input directory. For example /source/input/backup/

```
#!/bin/bash
day=$(date +%Y%m%d)
mkdir -p /target/backup/$day/ && mv /source/input/* /target/backup/$day/
```

Comment: Note that backticks are deprecated for this use. All shells compliant with the 1992 POSIX sh specification support `$(...)`, which is a generally safer approach (nests properly, doesn't change the meaning of backticks or backslashes within).

Comment: BTW, do you really want to `mv` source? That would make it no longer exist in the `/source/input` directory, which certainly seems like it would be the Wrong Thing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks Charles for excellent comments! backticks are deprecated is really nice. I myself have type error when I initially follow the script. Refer to second comments, the source folder is not a uniqe copy of source files. It just for easy maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh -x

init() {

day=$(date +%Y%m%d)
mkdir -p /target/backup/"${day}"/

cat > edpop+.txt << EOF
1d
wq
EOF

cat > edprint+.txt << EOF
1p
q
EOF

cat > edrep+.txt << EOF
%s/^/\/source\/input\//
wq
EOF

ls -la /source/input | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f9 > stack+.txt
ed -s stack+.txt < edpop+.txt
ed -s stack+.txt < edpop+.txt
ed -s stack+.txt < edrep+.txt
next
}

end () {
rm -v edpop+.txt
rm -v edprint+.txt
rm -v edrep+.txt
exit 0
}

next () {
[[ -s stack+.txt ]] && main
end
}

main () {
line=$(ed -s stack+.txt < edprint+.txt)
mv -v "${line}" /target/backup/"${day}"/
ed -s stack+.txt < edpop+.txt
next
}

init
```

There might be some minor bugs, because I haven't actually tested this one; but I'm pretty sure it will work.

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section "Answer Well-Asked Questions", and the guidance to close, rather than answer, questions that do not specify a specific, narrow problem. Writing someone else's program for them is exactly what we try *not* to do here.

Comment: I apologise.  I've seen so many entries around here recently where someone has essentially dumped a bare description of the problem and said "fix it," that I had actually started to think that was the norm.

Comment: @petrus4 Actually I have answered my own question. I think I share this knowledge and my English language skill is not good so that you missed my own answer.